# how to make my form not required to upload files in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

If i have double form at the same page , and one of them is for uploading files .

And sometime i will upload files and sometimes , I don't need for that , just need to edit at the first form inputs .

But it's not editing with me , because , that form having both of them is of type file ! 
How can i make this form not required to upload files

I'm using this code for that :

```
 <?= $this->Form->create($contractor, ['type' => 'file','required'=>false]) ?>
```

Comment: Form does not use required attribute. You have to do it with your form field. If you can provide the whole code of the form then i can tell your where to put it. It will be like this `$this->Form->control('file', ['required' => false]);`. Check this https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#html5-required. Or if you want to skip the whole validation then replace `'required'=>false` by `'formnovalidate' => true`

Comment: is it JavaScript or the framework (CakePHP) that is causing the form submit to fail due to no file?

Comment: @BarryChapman It's html5 form validations which is restring the form to submit. The form is created with some cakephp function which puts the validation as default to the form as per the model rules.

Comment: did you try this on model. like $validator->allowEmpty('file', 'create');

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Model validation,
This will make file upload field is an optional once in your form.

```
$validator->add('picture', 'file', [
'rule' => ['uploadedFile', ['optional' => true]]]);
```

Reference link : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation

I hope. This is useful for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is client side validation. You need to add the `novalidate` attribute to your form.

```
<form method="post" action="/myaction" novalidate>
   ...
</form>
```

Add that attribute and you should be good to go!